# How to pass python lists as a column_name and values to MySQL insert statement

Tags: python, mysql, list, insert

I have 2 lists...
Here is code

```
field_name = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
field_value = [('sathish','Twenty', 'Male'),('sam','Twenty_three', 'Male'), 
('suba','Twenty_one', 'FeMale')]
```

I already have table 'test' in my database with has more field_names 
I need to pass the column_name and values dynamically

my aim is to create an insert statement like

insert into test (*field_name) values (*field_value)

Assume I don't know the list values i.e Name, age, gender

How could I create an insert statement for the above list to insert values into the table

thanks in advance

```
'qry = "insert into test_ex" + field_name + "values".format(%s)'
'crsr.execute(qry, field_Value)'
```

Comment: `cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO test (' + ', '.join(field_name) + ') VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', field_value)` Can you check with this?

Comment: I am passing the list dyanmically.... ie the length of the list varies.. but both lists will have same length

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cursor.executemany()` for inserting multiple rows which takes `query` and `list of tuples` as arguments.
So you can generate a SQL query and add to `executemany` like below:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO test (' + ', '.join(field_name) + ') VALUES (' + ', '.join(['%s' for i in range(len(field_name))]) + ')', field_value)
```

So, this will become `cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO test (Name, Age, Gender) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', field_value)` for your above example.

Comment: I execute the above statement but the error message is:  not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Are you sure the length of `field_name` list and length of every `tuple` the same?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Gang... This one is the best answer for me... Thank you so much

Comment: It's Gagan, not Gang. And please mark this answer as best answer for your question.